# A method to extract router info in a LAN

Tags: router, lan

I am talking about a LAN in my building which has got 8 routers. I have admin access to all routers.
I am working on a project, part of which requires me to collect info about routers.
This info includes data transfer rates, No. of devices connected.

If my computer is connected to the LAN is it possible to extract info of a router using a python script or a java program (Trying to avoid SNMP) ?

I am using Linux on my computer and all the routers are D-Link routers with SNMP feature

Answer (score 0):

Besides SNMP, network equipment vendors are integrating API capabilities into their operating systems to simplify network management but that's not D-Link's case. You could try to write a Python script to log into the router's webGUI, grab the HTML data and parse it... but that's an awful solution.

Your best bet is SNMP, there's [PySNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/): a well documented, easy to use SNMP library for Python.